# VS2010 64 bit configuration using 32 bit compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a 64-bit Windows 7 laptop, using VS2010.  I have a solution with multiple projects that originally only had the 32 bit platform.  I used the Configuration Manager to create the x64 platform, and tried to build.  The problem is that the 32 bit compiler is used, then the linker fails with the message "fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'".

This has worked with other solutions and projects I have.  Why is it insisting on using the 32  bit compiler, and how do I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: One of the object files being passed to the linker is an x86 object.  You need to figure out which one.  Look at the linker command line and inspect each object to find the rogue object.

Comment: You would have to dig a very deep hole to get a 32-bit compile out of the x64 configuration.  Nothing is impossible, we do get some pretty terminal cases at SO.  But the simplest explanation is usually the right one, you'll get this linker error when you link a .lib that wasn't built by a project in your solution.  Easy enough to do when you have a dependency on a library that you downloaded from somewhere.  Don't skip the 64-bit version of "Hello world".